# Does debit card fraud indicate that I did something wrong?

Tags: fraud, debit-card

I'm quite careful with my debit card; I don't enter it on non-trustworthy sites. I just had a fraudulent transaction, so I'll need to get a new card. When I get the new card, do I need to be more careful with it than this one (not sure how I could be more careful other than by not using it online at all)? As far as I remember, I've never swiped it; all purchases have been online, chip, or tap.

Comment: No, there are things you can do to reduce your risk, but ultimately, fraudsters are clever - they might have, for example, tampered with the card reader at one of the restaurants where you used your card.

Comment: @user253751 okay. So just use the new card like I did the old one, and then if that one gets stolen as well, be more careful in the future? I don't think I've ever used the card in-person somewhere where I couldn't see it the whole time; my guess is that a Web site I used it on got hacked.

Comment: A hacked website is one possibility. Shops can also get hacked - even if you can see the card, the card reader or the shop's server could be hacked. There's also the idea that people could read your card wirelessly from a distance, but I think that's still science-fiction at this point.

Comment: @user253751 well, it is possible to hold a tap-to-pay point of sale up to someone's pocket, and you might not notice that in a crowd, but I haven't been out of the house for a couple days.

Comment: I thought chip transactions were immune to skimmers and the information could only be used for one transaction? This card has never been swiped AFAIK.

Comment: What is your goal?  It is possible that you used an ATM or payment device that had a skimmer installed which stole your card number.  You could be more suspicious of physical card readers.  You could limit what you consider a "trustworthy" site and avoid saving your card anywhere.  But if you are just concerned with the inconvenience of having a card replaced, you'd have to compare that to the inconvenience of having to enter your card number manually every time you want to buy something online.  If you're worried about liability, using a credit card rather than a debit card is preferred.

Comment: @JustinCave oh, it could have been an ATM. I will be more careful about both physical readers and Web sites in the future. Some things like my phone bill require saving the card, but one-time purchases don't. I'm okay with entering the info manually.

Answer (score 6):

What is the problem you are trying to solve?

If your goal is merely to avoid the inconvenience of getting a card replaced, you could be more security conscious.  Unfortunately, this usually comes at a cost of inconveniencing yourself.  It is possible that you were the victim of a [skimmer](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/credit-cards/how-to-spot-a-credit-card-skimmer/) that was installed in some ATM/ gas pump/ point-of-sale device that captured your card.  You could be more cautious about inspecting any devices you use.  That can be an annoyance if you need to get cash or gas frequently.  It is possible that a site you've purchased from was hacked.  You could limit the amount of sites you consider "trustworthy" and limit where your card is saved.  But that means entering your number more frequently and limiting what stores you purchase from.

If the goal is to avoid financial loss, particularly in the short term, it would be preferable (at least in the US) to use a credit card so that any fraudulent transactions are using the bank's money not your money.  Banks will usually credit back any money the fraudster takes pretty quickly but depending on how much money you generally keep in your checking account and how much the fraudster took, you could find yourself unexpectedly short when the bank tries to clear a payment you intended.